# convert Microsoft SQL Server specific query to ORACLE specific query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Hi all I have the following query written for Microsoft SQL Server.
I need to convert this query to Oracle syntax. I do not have any knowledge in Oracle syntax.
I need your help to make this query work on Oracle database.
I tried many ways but no data returned.

```
    SELECT SISPREV_student.Stu_Id, SISPREV_student.CwId,
 SISPREV_student.Sex, SISPREV_student.Nok_Name, SISPREV_student.Nok2_Name, 
              SISPREV_student.Birth_Dt,
 SISPREV_student.Currently_Enrolled, SISPREV_student.Stu_Athlete, SISPREV_student.LivingOnCampus, 
              SISPREV_student.ImmigrationStatus,
 SISPREV_student.ScholarStatus, SISPREV_student.Stu_FirstName, SISPREV_student.Stu_MiddleName,

              SISPREV_student.Stu_LastName, SISPREV_student.Ethnicity
FROM         SISPREV_address RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      SISPREV_student ON SISPREV_address.StudentID =
 SISPREV_student.Stu_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      SISPREV_email ON SISPREV_student.Stu_Id =
 SISPREV_email.StudentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      SISPREV_phone ON SISPREV_student.Stu_Id =
 SISPREV_phone.StudentID
WHERE ((SISPREV_student.Stu_Id LIKE '%' + '@StudentId' + '%') OR
 ('@StudentId' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_student.Stu_FirstName) LIKE '%' +
 UPPER('@StudentFirstName') + '%') OR ('@StudentFirstName' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_student.Stu_MiddleName) =
 UPPER('@StudentMiddleName')) OR ('@StudentMiddleName' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_student.Stu_LastName) LIKE '%' +
 UPPER('@StudentLastName') + '%') OR ('@StudentLastName' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_student.Nok_Name) LIKE '%' +
 UPPER('@StudentNextOfKinName') + '%') OR ('@StudentNextOfKinName' = '')) AND 
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_address.Street) LIKE '%' + UPPER('@StudentStreet') +
 '%') OR ('@StudentStreet' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_address.City) LIKE '%' + UPPER('@StudentCity') +
 '%') OR ('@StudentCity' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_address.State) LIKE '%' + UPPER('@StudentState') +
 '%') OR ('@StudentState' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_address.ZipCode) LIKE '%' + '@StudentZipCode' + '%'
 ) OR ('@StudentZipCode' = '')) AND
      ((SISPREV_student.Birth_Dt = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'@StudentBirthDay')) OR ('@StudentBirthDay' = '')) AND 
      ((SISPREV_phone.Phone = '@StudentPhoneNumber') OR
 ('@StudentPhoneNumber' = '')) AND
      ((UPPER(SISPREV_student.Sex) = UPPER('@StudentGender')) OR
 ('@StudentGender' = ''))
GROUP BY SISPREV_student.Stu_Id, SISPREV_student.CwId,
 SISPREV_student.Sex, SISPREV_student.Nok_Name, SISPREV_student.Nok2_Name, 
              SISPREV_student.Birth_Dt,
 SISPREV_student.Currently_Enrolled, SISPREV_student.Stu_Athlete, SISPREV_student.LivingOnCampus, 
              SISPREV_student.ImmigrationStatus,
 SISPREV_student.ScholarStatus, SISPREV_student.Stu_FirstName, SISPREV_student.Stu_MiddleName,

              SISPREV_student.Stu_LastName, SISPREV_student.Ethnicity
```

Comment: >“ I tried many ways”
What _did_ you try?

Comment: Make a short, readable version of the query, and perhaps someone will spend some time showing you the Oracle equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following needs to change:

```
((upper(sisprev_address.street) like '%' + upper('@StudentStreet') + '%')
```

In Oracle || is concatenation not +

```
((upper(sisprev_address.street) like '%' || upper('@StudentStreet') || '%') or ('@StudentStreet' = ''))
```

If @StudentStreet comes from user input and can be empty you can check that in Oracle as

```
or ('@StudentStreet' is null)
```

Date:

```
convert(smalldatetime, '@StudentBirthDay')
```

Dependig on the way you receive the date string

```
to_date('@StudentBirthDay','some date format')
```

'some date format' ='DD-MM-YYYY' or whatever format you handle. Look up Oracle data format strings.